# PasswordResetView in Django Allauth throwing invalid lookup error

Tags: django, django-models

I'm trying to override the `PasswordResetView` template. I've done so successfully by just creating a directory called `account` and placing `password_reset.html` My url looks liek this:

```
url(r'^recover/$', PasswordResetView.as_view(), name='account_reset_password')
```

Everything works fine, however, when I submit an email to have the password reset, I get the following error:

```
Related Field got invalid lookup: is_active
```

I'm not sure why this is happening. I'm using `allauth` and also Django's `auth` but for this particular instance i'm using the `allauth` views.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\samal\PycharmProjects\env\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py", line 47, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "C:\Users\samal\PycharmProjects\env\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py", line 179, in _get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\samal\PycharmProjects\env\lib\site-packages\django\views\generic\base.py", line 73, in view
    return self.dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\samal\PycharmProjects\env\lib\site-packages\django\views\generic\base.py", line 101, in dispatch
    return handler(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\samal\PycharmProjects\env\lib\site-packages\allauth\account\views.py", line 103, in post
    if form.is_valid():
  File "C:\Users\samal\PycharmProjects\env\lib\site-packages\django\forms\forms.py", line 177, in is_valid
    return self.is_bound and not self.errors
  File "C:\Users\samal\PycharmProjects\env\lib\site-packages\django\forms\forms.py", line 172, in errors
    self.full_clean()
  File "C:\Users\samal\PycharmProjects\env\lib\site-packages\django\forms\forms.py", line 374, in full_clean
    self._clean_fields()
  File "C:\Users\samal\PycharmProjects\env\lib\site-packages\django\forms\forms.py", line 395, in _clean_fields
    value = getattr(self, 'clean_%s' % name)()
  File "C:\Users\samal\PycharmProjects\env\lib\site-packages\allauth\account\forms.py", line 502, in clean_email
    self.users = filter_users_by_email(email, is_active=True)
  File "C:\Users\samal\PycharmProjects\env\lib\site-packages\allauth\account\utils.py", line 395, in filter_users_by_email
    mails = mails.filter(user__is_active=is_active)
  File "C:\Users\samal\PycharmProjects\env\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\query.py", line 942, in filter
    return self._filter_or_exclude(False, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\samal\PycharmProjects\env\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\query.py", line 962, in _filter_or_exclude
    clone._filter_or_exclude_inplace(negate, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\samal\PycharmProjects\env\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\query.py", line 969, in _filter_or_exclude_inplace
    self._query.add_q(Q(*args, **kwargs))
  File "C:\Users\samal\PycharmProjects\env\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\sql\query.py", line 1358, in add_q
    clause, _ = self._add_q(q_object, self.used_aliases)
  File "C:\Users\samal\PycharmProjects\env\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\sql\query.py", line 1380, in _add_q
    split_subq=split_subq, check_filterable=check_filterable,
  File "C:\Users\samal\PycharmProjects\env\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\sql\query.py", line 1319, in build_filter
    condition = self.build_lookup(lookups, col, value)
  File "C:\Users\samal\PycharmProjects\env\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\sql\query.py", line 1156, in build_lookup
    raise FieldError('Related Field got invalid lookup: {}'.format(lookup_name))

Exception Type: FieldError at /recover/
Exception Value: Related Field got invalid lookup: is_active
```

**Custom User Model**

```
class User(AbstractBaseUser):
    username = models.CharField(max_length=15)

    email = models.EmailField(max_length=100, unique=True,
                              error_messages={
                                  'unique': "Email has already been taken."
                              })

    date_joined = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True,
                                       null=True) 
    active = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    staff = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    admin = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    objects = UserManager()

    USERNAME_FIELD = 'username'
    REQUIRED_FIELDS = ['email']  # Username and password are required by default

    def __str__(self):
        return self.username

    def get_full_name(self):
        return self.username

    def get_short_name(self):
        return self.username

    def has_perm(self, perm, obj=None):
        "Does the user have a specific permission?"
        # Simplest possible answer: Yes, always
        return True

    def has_module_perms(self, app_label):
        "Does the user have permissions to view the app `app_label`"
        # Simplest possible answer: Yes, always
        return True

    @property
    def is_active(self):
        # is the user active?
        return self.active

    @property
    def is_staff(self):
        # is the user a staff member?
        return self.staff

    @property
    def is_admin(self):
        # is the user an admin?
        return self.admin
```

Comment: Add the full traceback to your question

Comment: @IainShelvington just added thanks

Comment: Do you have a custom user model? Seems like an issue with that. Add it to the question if you do?

Comment: It means your custom user model has no `is_active` field.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem it has an `active` field. How would I make it so that it can check `is_active` instead?

Comment: @IainShelvington I have updated the question with custom user model. My model has an `active` field and not an `is_active` field

Comment: Probably, you need to override the `PasswordResetView` or corresponding model form where the lookup is taking place

Answer (score 0):

So, I was able to find a solution to the problem; however, I don't think this is the most elegant solution.

Regardless, my solution was just to add another field in my UserModel called 'is_active.' Notably, I deleted the is_active property from my model too.

```
class User(AbstractBaseUser):
   username = models.CharField(max_length=150, unique=False)
   email = models.EmailField(max_length=255, unique=True)
   active = models.BooleanField(default=True)
   staff = models.BooleanField(default=False)
   admin = models.BooleanField(default=False)
   timestamp = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

   # Required by Django allauth
   is_active = models.BooleanField(default=True) <-- This Line Here!

   USERNAME_FIELD = "email"
   REQUIRED_FIELDS = ["username"] #Fields that should be required.

   objects = UserManager()

   def __str__(self):
       return "ID: {0} | Username: {1} | Email: {2}".format(str(self.pk), str(self.username), str(self.email))
    
   def get_full_name(self):
       return self.username

   def get_short_name(self):
       return self.username

   def has_perm(self, perm, obj=None):
       return self.admin

   def has_module_perms(self, app_label):
       return True

   @property
   def is_staff(self):
       return self.staff

   @property
   def is_admin(self):
       return self.admin
```

Again, this is definitely not the most elegant solution around. I would like to see what others were able to come up with.